# releaseDC() delete the DC?

Tags: winapi

I need to keep track of a list of hDC's, However, I noticed taht every time I GetDC(), I need to ReleaseDC(). Otherwise I will get NULL.

The question is, should I store all the hDC's when I GetDC()? or I need to store hWnd and use GetDC() when I need a hDC?

Comment: What does OpenGL have to do with this?

Comment: *Never* store a hDC, that just adds more problems.  A stale one whose clipping region no longer matches the window surface is an ugly problem.  They are dirt-cheap to create and destroy, the ReleaseDC() call should never be far away from the GetDC() call.  If it is too far away then refactor to move painting code into another function.

Comment: I would opt to store the `HWND`s and then retrieve their `HDC`s on an as-needed basis.

Comment: The title is confusing since it talks about deleting the DC, but the question has nothing to do with the `DeleteDC` function (which deletes DCs).

Comment: @HansPassant could you explain why never store a hDC. Is it because when releaseDC(), the stored hDC will also be released?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even need to store hdc?
hdc are just pointers, so even if you store it, it gets changes or altered when ReleaseDC is called or any other DC operation is done..
I hope u understand how pointers work.

You need to ReleaseDC after every GetDC otherwise you wont get desired output.